# Fill a dataframe from another one based on two conditions

Tags: python, function, dataframe, merge, lookup

I am a little stuck on a small project I am working on and I would appreciate your help.

I have two data frames.

The first one is larger and it is the one I want to use for my final analyses.

It contains ISIN for bonds based on industry, region and has ratings from S&P and Moody’s.

ISIN

Industry

Region

SP

MD

The second data has Industry, rating(S&P and Moody’s) and region as well as an estimated rating based on financial information like investments, spending on R&D etc.

Industry

Region

SP

MD

Internal Estimate

I would like to extract in a new column in the first database the internal rating based on the Industry, Region and Rating labeled “Internal Estimate”.

A merge wouldn’t work because in an industry you can have several S&P and Moody’s ratings or even sometimes those are missing.

That is why I have written a code with the following conditions:

For i in range (1: i):

```
 if Bond_Rating[‘MD’]='' and Bond_Ratings[‘SP’]='':

     Bond_Rating[Internal Estimate] = ''

    elif  Bond_Rating['MD']='' and Bond_Rating[‘SP’]!='':

       Bond_Rating['INTERNAL ESTIMATE']= Bond_Rating.lookup[concat('BicId','RegionName',’SP’),INTERNAL ESTIMATE.Table[‘InternalEstimate’]]

    elif  Bond_Rating['MD']!='' and Bond_Rating[‘SP’]='':

        Bond_Rating['INTERNAL ESTIMATE']= Bond_Rating.lookup[concat('BicId','RegionName','MD'), INTERNAL ESTIMATE.Table[‘InternalEstimate’]]

    elif  Bond_Rating['MD']!='' and Bond_Rating[‘SP’] !='':

        Bond_Rating['INTERNAL ESTIMATE']= Bond_Rating.lookup[concat('BicId','RegionName','MD',’SP’), INTERNAL ESTIMATE.Table[‘InternalEstimate’]]
```

However, I am unsure why my code doesn’t work. I keep getting errors.

I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: `=` is for assignment. `==` is for testing equality. You're using `=` for testing equality in various places. Beyond that you'll have to actually show us the errors you're getting before we can help you any more.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks for noticing. Well I did the code in VBA before but I have to move to Python. However, that is a challenge as I don't know how Python accepts functions and how best to write it. The errors I keep getting, when I execute the above code is that I cannot compare booleans(for the Moody's and S&P condition) and I don't even go to the Internal Estimate column in the other dataframe.

Comment: As I mentioned the problem with a simple merge is that I do not have the same level of combination of ratings in the first dataframe and the second one. That is why I have to write a function that pulls the internal estimate from the second dataframe based on whether the value of Moody's and S&P(nto all of the rows have values). Any suggestions would be welcomed. I tried to find a solution searching stakcoverflow but couldn't, so that is why I posted my question.